# Error - jhipster-native - TypeError: contents.replaceAll is not a function

Tags: jhipster, graalvm, spring-native

I am creating a monolith app with jhipster-native. I got the following error.

```
ERROR! contents.replaceAll is not a function
```

> TypeError: contents.replaceAll is not a function
> at file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/generators/server/generator.mjs:311:57
> at default.editFile (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/generators/server/generator.mjs:447:17)
> at default.replaceUndertowWithTomcat (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/generators/server/generator.mjs:311:16)
> at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1097:23)
> at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
> at new Promise ()
> at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19
> at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1098:9
> at new Promise ()
> at default.executeTask (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1069:12)

The jhipster-native options are below.

Thank you in advance!

```html
===================== JHipster Native =====================

     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-native for app subgenerator
Application files will be generated in folder: /Users/albanomataj/Projects/amataj/jhipster-examples/spring-native
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/
  If you find JHipster useful, consider sponsoring the project at https://opencollective.com/generator-jhipster
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? jhipster
     info Using blueprint generator-jhipster-native for server subgenerator
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? No
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication (stateful, works with Keycloak and Okta)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? PostgreSQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) No cache - Warning, when using an SQL database, this will disable the Hibernate 2nd level cache!
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which other technologies would you like to use?
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular
? Do you want to generate the admin UI? Yes
? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Default JHipster
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use?
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

Comment: @MattRaible I followed the article at https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/03/03/spring-native-jhipster. I might have missed some detail.

Comment: What version of Node and npm do you have installed? I used Node 16 when testing.

Comment: @MattRaible You are right. I was using a version of node older than 16. I upgraded node to 16. It worked. Thank You for the answer. Thank You for jhipster-native!